# Two copies of an app taking space

Tags: insufficient-memory

My old HTC M8 is running very low on space, and I noticed it has 2 copies of several apk installed in /data/app for example com.twitter.android-2 and com.twitter.android-3. All in, this appears to be taking 1Gb.

This phone is rooted, so I can fix it, but is this a bug or just an artifact of the phone being old and having had several OTA updates in its time?

Would I be able to test/fix this without being rooted (except for factory reset).

OS version is 6.0

```
com.twitter.android-1:
-rw-r--r--    1 system   system    33495510 Nov 14 20:41 base.apk
drwxr-xr-x    3 system   system        4096 Nov 14 20:41 lib
drwxrwx--x    3 system   install       4096 Nov 14 20:41 oat

com.twitter.android-2:
-rw-r--r--    1 system   system    38637594 Aug 13 08:31 base.apk
drwxr-xr-x    3 system   system        4096 Aug 13 08:31 lib
drwxrwx--x    3 system   install       4096 Aug 13 08:32 oat
```

Comment: The expected behavior, from Lollipop onwards, is for Android to incrementally rename the directory in which an APK is placed, each time an update occurs. Is your device rooted? If yes, could you show us the permissions, ownership and attributes of `com.twitter.android-2` and `com.twitter.android-3`?

Comment: updated. Maybe relevant that the phone rarely sees wifi for any length of time, I keep it in the car (so it may often get partial updates).

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman is it normal that the second directory is kept *after the update completed?* To my understanding, as soon as that step is finished the "older directory" is removed. In my case, if it was not, the result was a bootloop (remember?).

Comment: @Izzy It is not normal indeed. As I said, the directory is normally renamed once the update is completed.

Comment: To my experience, the older one is removed. If I list contents of `/data/app`, some directories end on `-1`, others on `-2` – but there's always only one directory per app. But be that as it might: 2 directories per app is *not* normal, on that we seem to agree – so something must be going wrong there.